# git push is failing because of not asking token for login

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, intellij-13

I have a github repository in my organisation where I am a member of it.
I did cloning of that repository from intelliJ into using the token which i have created in my git account. I have added the remote in intelliJ using the same server name and token.
[image]

I am able to clone this repository and after updating the code, while trying to push the code  back to repository it is again asking for the userID and password. It is not showing the option to login with token itself, as shown below. (If I give the username and password instead of token it will not work)
[image]

Because of this i am not able to push any code changes into git. This was working fine earlier either without asking any login page or with login page which have option to provide token. I didnt make any changes in settings, but now facing this issue for last few days.

Is there anything that i have to make changes in settings?
Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

IDE saves all passwords, including GitHub token, according to the settings in Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Passwords.
Make sure IDE is configured to save passwords either in Keychain or in KeePass, so you won't be prompted to enter login and password again.

When prompted for credentials, either enter token as username and leave the password field empty or use the token instead of your password.
(Please see: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206537004-How-to-access-GIT-remote-repositories-with-2-factor-authentication)

Regarding SSH connection:
IDE relies on command-line Git, whereas in its turn Git sends a request to SSH client, so it may worth to check ssh config and see how it's configured.
Also please check whether you have SSH or HTTPS URL specified under VCS | Git | Remotes..

Comment: Only the second way has worked for me: specify your username and put token into the password field.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't created your sshkey and added to your gitlab account that's why it is asking for user id and password again, Work after setting ssh key is better approach to work on project

Comment: One more thing i have to add is push is working for another repository under the same organization. But even though some times it will also fail by asking the same.
SSH key was already created and added to github. Anyways I will try generating ssh key again and try again

Comment: If you go to the pub file which is created after running ssh-keygen is made using user username email your system password and machine name if you password change recently then you have to generate new sshkey and add to your gitlab

Comment: Created new ssh keys and added to ssh agent and in github account. Still not working!

Comment: Check your HOME variable your git always check for that path for .gitconfig and .ssh folder you can set permanently HOME path by going to edit the environment variables in your windows or by command use export in bash and setenv in csh